# Nested UICollectionView does not bounce

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I have a UICollectionView that contains two other UICollectionsViews. This was done so that I could have each "section" scrollable/bouncing independently from one another.

I initialize the sub-UICollectionViews like so:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *subCollectionLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
[subCollectionLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];

otherCollection = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:subCollectionFrame collectionViewLayout:subCollectionLayout];
thisCollection = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:subCollectionFrame collectionViewLayout:subCollectionLayout];

//Allow bouncing
[otherCollection setBounces:YES];
[thisCollection setBounces:YES];
[otherCollection alwaysBounceHorizontal];
[thisCollection alwaysBounceHorizontal];
```

Everything appears as expected, minus the bouncing. I have been looking around, but to no avail. Any thoughts as to why this happens?